# How can I initialize a std::map with opposite signature coordinate keys?

Tags: c++, coordinates, std, comparator, stdmap

For some background information, I am trying to create a quick quadtree generation algorithm using a dictionary lookup. The basic concept involves mapping coordinates to quadtree nodes via binary representation:

```
struct vec2 { // Test coordinate object
    double x, y; // replacing double with signed int everywhere does not achieve results either
    vec2(const double& x = NULL, const double& y = NULL)
        : x(x), y(y) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vec2 vector)
    {
        return os << "(" << vector.x << ", " << vector.y << ")\n";
    }
    bool operator()(const vec2& lhs, const vec2& rhs) const
    {
        /* TODO: make proper sorting function */
        if ((lhs.x < rhs.x) && (lhs.y < rhs.y)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (std::hypot(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::hypot(rhs.x, rhs.y)) {
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
};

std::map<vec2, std::bitset<4>, vec2> nodeLoc = { // quadtree node mapping
            { ( 1, 1), 1000 }, // first quadrant
            { (-1, 1), 0100 }, // second quadrant
            { (-1,-1), 0010 }, // third quadrant
            { ( 1,-1), 0001 }, // fourth quadrant
            { ( 0, 0), 0000 }, 
            { ( 0, 1), 1100 }, // first and second
            { ( 0,-1), 0011 }, // third and fourth
            { ( 1, 0), 1001 }, // first and fourth
            { (-1, 0), 0110 }, // second and third
};

int main() {

    std::cout << nodeLoc[(-1, -1)];

    return 0;
}
```

The main function should print `0010` to the console, but it prints `1000` instead. The map function is identifying `(-1, -1)` with `(1, 1)`, but I thought that the definition for the `bool operator()` would prevent these from being identified as the same input. I tried creating a hash function to use with an `std::unordered_map`, but wound up with a similar problem (albeit a little different since `(-1,1)` would map the same as `(1,-1)` instead).

How can I appropriately create a map between signed coordinates and their binary node representation?

Comment: `(0, 1)` is .. just `1` (comma operator involved. you probably want `{0, 1}` instead.

Comment: In the same way for `bitset`, you probably want `"1000"` or `0b1000` instead of `1000`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yup, thank you. I did not realize putting the integers in as `0001` or `0100` would just shift them over to `1` and `100` respectively, making them synonymous with `1000` to the `bitset<4>`, although I should have expected as much. Seems that now I just need to find an adequate sorting/hashing function.

Comment: In fact `0100` is `64` (octal (base 8) used).

Comment: How about lexicographic order: `bool operator()(const vec2& lhs, const vec2& rhs) const { return std::tie(lhs.x, lhs.y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);` or even `auto operator <=>(const vec2& rhs) const = default` (C++20).

Comment: @Jarod42 that works perfectly. I saw a similar solution in another stack thread, but I couldn't figure out why it was not working for me when I tried to implement it. I didn't realize that the parenthesis and the `bitset` initialization formatting would have such a huge impact, or even that I was initializing the `vec2`s and `bitset`s incorrectly. I really appreciate you reviewing my code and giving me feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compiler can point out two crucial mistakes in your code:

#### There are no null references

```cpp
warning: converting to non-pointer type 'double' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
    9 |     vec2(const double& x = NULL, const double& y = NULL)
      |                            ^~~~
```

Firstly, what you're doing is essentially `const double& x = 0` in that code. There is no such thing as a null reference in C++, which seems like what you're trying to create. Also not that a `const&` can bind to a temporary value (temporary materialization), so that the code compiles.

To solve this, either delete the constructor completely, which makes `vec2` an aggregate type. Alternatively:

```cpp
// note: don't use default arguments because they would allow initialization
//       with just one argument, which is undesirable
vec2(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
vec2() : vec2(0, 0) {}
```

#### `(1, 1)` is a comma expresssion, not a constructor call

The second mistake is using this syntax:

```cpp
warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
   30 |             { ( 1, 1), 1000 }, // first quadrant
      |                 ^
```

`(1, 1)` is not doing `vec2(1, 1)`, it's using the comma operator, where the left `1` is discarded, and the right `1` is used to call `vec2(1)`. Your original constructor can be called with just one argument, and isn't `explicit`, so an implicit conversion from `1` to `vec2` was possible.

To fix this, use `{ { 1, 1}, 1000 }`, where the inner `{ 1, 1}` is equivalent to `vec2(1, 1)`.

#### Further notes

- `1000` is a decimal literal; you should provide a binary literal `0b1000` when initializing a `std::bitset`
- `vec2` should not be the function object provided to `std::map`; you can simply turn `operator()` into `operator<` and use `std::map<vec2, std::bitset<4>>`

  - alternatively, define a three-way comparison operator
- `nodeLoc` should be declared as `const` ideally, and instead of `nodeLoc[(x, y)]` (which also uses the comma operator), write `nodeLoc.at({x, y})`

---

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ddPKnn9M4) with all changes implemented*